# How to set and use PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR environment variable in PHP?

Tags: php, configuration, environment-variables, php-ini, scandir

I've installed **PHP 7.2.3** on my machine running on **Windows 10**. I've installed PHP and **Apache httpd 4.29** using latest copy of **XAMPP package**.

I come across following text from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.scan)

> It is possible to configure PHP to scan for .ini files in a directory
>   after reading `php.ini`. This can be done at compile time by setting the
>   **--with-config-file-scan-dir** option. In PHP 5.2.0 and later, the scan directory can then be overridden at run time by setting the
>   `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable.
>
> It is possible to scan multiple directories by separating them with
>   the platform-specific path separator (; on Windows, NetWare and RISC
>   OS; : on all other platforms; the value PHP is using is available as
>   the **PATH_SEPARATOR** constant). If a blank directory is given in
>   `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`, PHP will also scan the directory given at compile
>   time via **--with-config-file-scan-dir** .

I tried below code but couldn't set the environment variable `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`

```
        <?php
            $_ENV['PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR'] = "Jumbo";
            print_r(getenv());
        ?>
```

Someone please make me understand what exactly is `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` and how to use it/set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use Apaches SetEnv in a `.htaccess` file or `<vhost>` section.
  https://serverfault.com/questions/224685/php-ini-disable-scan-this-dir-for-additional-ini-files

  ```
  SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR C:/web/app/conf.d/
  ```
- On Windows you can also go to the control panel and set a [global environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10), or configure it per-service AFAIK.
- Or install MSVC and [recompile PHP](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) to set custom `./configure` options (such as `--with-config-file-scan-dir`).

  > *You* probably do not want to do that.